# bluetooth beacon still running in background even the app is closed android

Tags: android

I'm using library from https://github.com/adriancretu/beacons-android. The beacon still running on background even I close the app. Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

These instructions in the README may help you:

> IMPORTANT! A minimum-priority notification allows the user to stop all
>   currently running beacons, for the following reason. If your app
>   crashes or the beacons service is killed and restarted,
>   all savedactive beacons will restart advertising. A device has a
>   maximum number of concurrent BLE broadcasters (4 on Nexus 6; 8
>   on Galaxy S7, etc.). When this number is reached, new beacons will
>   fail to start. It's best to make sure you stop() or delete() a beacon
>   after you no longer need it, but the notification assures the user is
>   in control

```
beacon.stop()
```